# Pattern to store login credentials for a web based mobile app

Tags: architecture, web-applications, mobile

We are a small shop and focus on web development. We have a website that users need to login.

I want to outsource the "app" development by getting someone to build the app and packages for android and ios - but basically our website will be the application.

We've done a test that works fine, but the user lands on the homepage and has to login every time.

I'm looking for a pattern that I can use whereby the app will open and the user is automatically logged in through the website when the page is initially loaded. My question is - what is the simplest solution that I can implement this with the least dependencies between the app and the website?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a "pattern", but this is a common flow for programmatic login to single sign-on.

[image]

1. Native app makes API request to authentication service with user credentials.
2. If credentials are correct temporary session token is returned
3. Native app opens web view to authenticate session token
4. Browser navigates to authentication endpoint
5. Backend verifies session token with auth service
6. User claims are returned (if session token is valid)
7. Backend sends redirect to web browser with destination and sets a session cookie in the browser.

Inspiration from [here](https://pracucci.com/auto-login-from-native-apps-to-web.html).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good option for me - sorry don't have enough reps to upvote